# Need help understanding this following boolean expression in an if statement

Tags: java, short-circuiting, operator-precedence

Found from the Kathie Sierra book on OCA/OCP Java SE 7 Programmers I & II study guide:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 5;
if ((x > 3) && (y < 2) | doStuff()) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

> This now prints ... nothing! Because the preceding code (with one less
>   set of parentheses) evaluates as though you were saying, "If (x > 3)
>   is not true, and either (y < 2) or the result of doStuff() is true,
>   then print true. So if (x > 3) is not true, no point in looking at the
>   rest of the expression" Because of the short-circuit &&, the
>   expression is evaluated as though there were parentheses around (y <
>   2) | doStuff().

In my understanding, the operators `&&` and `||` has the same precedence and evaluated from left to right. So in this case, the expression `(x > 3) && (y < 2)` should still be evaluated first. Please explain.

Update: My mistake. It is indeed a "|" instead of a "||".

Comment: Is it binary or "|" or is it a true or operator "||"?

Comment: But && has lower precedence than bitwise inclusive OR.

Comment: Yes you are right. You should have answered (instead of commented) then I would have selected yours as answer.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I wouldn't necessarily expect it to print anything.  The condition `x > 3 && y < 2` is false for the given values of x and y.

I've had a moment now to reflect on the operator precedence, and basically, regardless of what `doStuff` says (true or false), if `x > 3` evaluates to `false`, it's not printing anything.

Effectively, this expression:

```
(x > 3) && (y < 2) | doStuff()
```

is equivalent to:

```
(x > 3) && (y < 2 | doStuff())
```

...and since `x > 3` is false for the given `x` value, the entire expression evaluates to false.  Here, `&&` will short-circuit the expression, without calling `doStuff`.